# Controllers design pattern

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, controllers

I have a design question about MVC and controllers

I have this two routes

```
Route::get('/foo/{id}', FooController@show)
Route::get('/bar/{id}', BarController@show)
```

But know, I would like to add another route for the index like this

```
Route::get('/', ???)
```

In this route, I need some information about the Foo and Bar models.
The question is, should I create a new controller for that route? like `MainController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, controllers are meant to respond to requests associated with a specific resource (model). Thereby, given your concrete example, two distinct scenarios apply.

1. The `Foo` and `Bar` models are required on the landing page (`/` route): In this case, a dedicated controller would be a perfectly fine thing to do. Also, the use of a view model would be beneficial.
2. No information about application-specific models is needed on the landing page: You can still use a dedicated controller class to return your view, while another possibility would be the use of a lambda function:

   ```
   Route::get('/', function () {
       return view('landing');
   });
   ```

Comment: Yeah, sure. But what if I need to use some information there to construct the index view?

Comment: @JulianMendez then you might want to create a dedicated controller which passes the required data to the view. Also, the use of a view model could be helpful in this situation.

Comment: Edit the answer to mark it as correct :D. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It has always worked best for me to have a controller per resource type.
You have the resource 'foo' with FooController, and 'bar' with BarController. So for the root context resource, you aught to have a root controller.

This helps with separation of concern and keeps your code modularized.

Comment: i thougth the same. But the thing is I need some information of the models I have to build de new view. I will edit my question right now